# Populating Domain Objects from XML using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am new to LINQ to XML and need help in mapping an XML hierarchy into my domain object. Here is the XML source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Listings>
    <Region>United States</Region>
    <Listing>
        <CatID>ELE</CatID>
        <CatDesc>Electronics</CatDesc>
        <ItemID>ELE_LCDTV</ItemID>
        <ItemDesc>LCD TV BLU RAY</ItemDesc>
        <TotalPrice>1500</TotalPrice>
    </Listing>
    <Listing>
        <CatID>COMP</CatID>
        <CatDesc>Computer</CatDesc>
        <ItemID>COMP_LAPTOP</ItemID>
        <ItemDesc>Laptop HP</ItemDesc>
        <TotalPrice>1200</TotalPrice>
    </Listing>
    <Listing>
        <CatID>MISC</CatID>
        <CatDesc>Miscellaneous</CatDesc>
        <ItemID>MISC_WII</ItemID>
        <ItemDesc>Wii</ItemDesc>
        <TotalPrice>350</TotalPrice>
    </Listing>
    <Listing>
        <CatID>COMP</CatID>
        <CatDesc>Computer</CatDesc>
        <ItemID>COMP_HD</ItemID>
        <ItemDesc>Hard Disk</ItemDesc>
        <TotalPrice>300</TotalPrice>
    </Listing>
    <Listing>
        <CatID>ELE</CatID>
        <CatDesc>Electronics</CatDesc>
        <ItemID>ELE_IPOD</ItemID>
        <ItemDesc>iPod</ItemDesc>
        <TotalPrice>225</TotalPrice>
    </Listing>
    <Listing>
        <CatID>COMP</CatID>
        <CatDesc>Computer</CatDesc>
        <ItemID>COMP_WKEY</ItemID>
        <ItemDesc>Wireless Keyboard</ItemDesc>
        <TotalPrice>110</TotalPrice>
    </Listing>
    <Listing>
        <CatID>MISC</CatID>
        <CatDesc>Miscellaneous</CatDesc>
        <ItemID>MISC_GAME</ItemID>
        <ItemDesc>Games</ItemDesc>
        <TotalPrice>50</TotalPrice>
    </Listing>
</Listings>
```

I have to populate following domain objects ushing above XML. Basically I have to expose an IEnumerable ListCategories()

```
public class Category
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IList<Item> Items { get; set; } 
}

public class Item
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }

}
```

I undersyand that I have to an orderby query first to sort the XML by CatID and then traverse through it to populate my domain objects.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(XmlizedString);

var listing = from x in xDoc.Elements("Listings").Elements("Listing")
                                           orderby (string)x.Element("CatID")
                                           select x;
```

Above query will sort my XML by CatID but I am not clear how to proceed further...

I would gretly appreciate your suggestions/help in resolving this.

Comment: Would you mind formatting your XML and placing inside a code block. Just for readability.

Comment: Hello Val, I just did that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Linq-to-xml query would look like this.

```
var listing = 
xDoc.Elements("Listings")
.Elements("Listing")
.GroupBy (x => new { 
                ID = x.Element(XName.Get("CatID")).Value
                , Description = x.Element(XName.Get("CatDesc")).Value
            }
)
.Select (x => new Category { 
                ID = x.Key.ID
                , Description = x.Key.Description
                , Items = x.Select (i => new Item { 
                                    ID = i.Element("ItemID").Value
                                    , Description = i.Element("ItemDesc").Value
                                    , TotalPrice = decimal.Parse(i.Element("TotalPrice").Value) 
                                   }
                    ).ToList()
            }
        )
.OrderBy (x => x.ID);
```

Comment: Thanks much MarkisT, your solution works like a charm. For some of the items, TotalPrice element might be missing from XML if there is no price and I am getting an exception for that. Is there a way to set 0.00 value for TotalPrice in case "TotalPrice" element is missing from XML?

Comment: coversly u can declare TotalPrice quality as nullable

Comment: Even if I try to make TotalPrice as nullable in my class I am getting an exception because exception is happing at following line of code         i.Element("TotalPrice").Value          as TotalPrice element itself is missing from source XML.

Comment: Leave the TotalPrice as nullable and then when you set TotalPrice in the select statement use this instead:

TotalPrice = i.Element("TotalPrice") != null ? decimal.Parse(i.Element("TotalPrice").Value) : null

Comment: Thanks MarkisT. Sorry I don't want to be a pain but I tried your suggestion but getting a compile time error. I made TotalPrice as nullable in my class like this -  public decimal? TotalPrice { get; set; } and I replaced your line of code - TotalPrice = i.Element("TotalPrice") != null ? decimal.Parse(i.Element("TotalPrice").Value):null AND I get following error: Error 1 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'decimal' and '<null>'

Comment: I resolved it by using following line of code: TotalPrice = decimal.Parse(i.Elements("TotalPrice").Any() ? i.Element("TotalPrice").Value : "0"). I hope I am correct. Thank you all.

Comment: That was the next thing I was going to suggest.  Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Linq-to-xml, however, if the query above iterates through your xml and returns an IEnumerable or similar thing you can populate your objects in following way:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(XmlizedString);

var listing = from x in xDoc.Elements("Listings").Elements("Listing")
              orderby (string)x.Element("CatID")
              select new Category {
                  ID = x.CatID, 
                  Description = x.CatDesc, 
                  Items = new Item { 
                      x.ItemID,  
                      Description = x.ItemDesc, 
                      TotalPrice = x.TotalPrice 
                  } 
              };
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Query I gave in my sample only helps me sort (order by) the XML by CatID but I would like to know how best can I populate by domain objects, I mean, Category object listing all categories and their corresponding items.